# pasar variable de js a php y poner en input

Tags: php, javascript

hola tengo una pequeño problema soy algo nuevo en php y js,
tengo script que toma una valor de select y lo almacena en una variable, esta variable sera el filtro del select de un sql para buscarlo en una tabla,
puedo hacer la conexión, tomar el dato seleccionado del select(html) pero al usarlo como filtro no carga ningún valor
pongo mi código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bpr()
    {
      //variables para obtener el valores del select (cb1)
      var codsele = document.getElementById("cb1");
      var see = codsele.options[codsele.selectedIndex].text;
     
     // alert(see);
      <?php
        $temp3 = $_GET["see"];
        
      //  $temp3 = "<script language='javascript'> document.fselect.cb1.value write(see) </script>";
                
        //conexion a bdd
        $conexion = new mysqli('xxx.xxx.xx.', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xx');
        //consulta a la tabla de la bdd
        $consulta ="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE pname= $temp3";
        $resultados=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        //variable para almacenar la consulta
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultados);
      ?>
        //var ultim = "<?php echo $fila[3];?>";
        //variable para obtener el resultado de la consulta y cargarlo a un input  
        var ultim = "<?php echo $temp3;?>";
        document.getElementById('vprecio').value = ultim; 
       //  document.getElementById('vprecio').value = "<?php echo($temp3);?>"; 
        

      }
         
  </script>
```

---

```
<--select que se llena con una consulta a bdd
  <form name="fselect" method="POST" >
          <select class="form-control" name="cb1" id= "cb1" onchange="enviar()" value="">
            <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
              <?php
                $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM productos");
                  while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
                    {
                    echo '<option value="'.$valores[idproducto].'">'.$valores[pname].'</option>';
                    }
                  $mysqli->close(); 
              ?>
          </select>
         
      </form>

<script>
        function enviar()
        {
            var codsele = document.getElementById("cb1");
            var mivarjsa = codsele.options[codsele.selectedIndex].text;
            var mivarjs = mivarjsa;
            
            alert(mivarjs);
            $.ajax
            (
              {
                type: 'post',
                url:'fileproc.php',
               data:{mivarjs: mivarjs},
               beforeSend:
               function()
                {
                  $("resultado").html("procesando wait....");
                },
                success:function(response)
                {
                  $("#resultado").html(response);
                }
               }
            );
          }

      </script>

///el otro archiv
<?php

    $res = $_POST['mivarjs'];
    $resa = $res;
    
    $conexion = new mysqli('192.168.0.10', 'root', '12061968', 'ttra');
    $consulta ="SELECT * FROM productos where pname = $res";
        $resultados=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultados);
        //$resultado = $fila[3];
        $resultado = $resa;

        echo $resultado;


if (isset($_POST['mivarjs']))
     {
        if ($_POST['mivarjs'])
            echo "recibido: "-$_POST['mivarjs'];
                    
         else
         echo "recibido campo vacio";
      }


 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**La solución está en usar AJAX.**

Has de pensar que JS se ejecuta en el lado del cliente y PHP en el lado del servidor.

Con AJAX mandas de forma asincrónica datos al servidor y los resultados  son devueltos

Para este ejemplo...

- Creas una página con el formulario y el js.
- Creas otra donde se trabaja con la variable y el PHP

Al cambiar el select este recoge el valor y lo manda mediante AJAX a un archivo PHP donde haces la tarea que necesites (buscar en la BBDD o lo que creasoprotuno).

El resultado lo puedes pintar en donde quieras en el ejemplo es un div en forma de texto y input.

**Página formulario.php** *(uso JQuery)*

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#select_values').on('change', function(){

      var tu_variable = $(this).val();


      $.ajax({
              url: "formulario_2.php",
              type: "POST",
              async: true,
              data: {
                tu_variable : tu_variable} ,
                    success: function(result) {
                       $('#resultado').html(result);

                    },
                    error: function(result) {

                  $('#resultado').html('Se ha producido un error.');
                    }
              });

      })
  });
</script>

<form>
  <select id="select_values">
  <option value="val_1">val_1</option>
  <option value="val_2">val_2</option>
  <option value="val_3">val_3</option>
  <option value="val_4">val_4</option>
</select>
</form>

<div id="resultado">
  Resultado de la variable= 0
</div>
```

**Página formulario_2.php**
Página donde haces lo que necesites con tu variable.

```
 <?php
     echo "La variable seleccionada es: ";
     echo "<input name='nuevo_input' value='".$_POST['tu_variable']."' />";
 ?>
```

Comment: gracias por contestar, adapte tu código si me devuelve el valor pero le agrega un 0 al texto no se porque anexo codigo

Comment: gracias por contestar, adapte tu código si me devuelve el valor pero le agrega un 0 al texto no se porque anexo código, si tengo los 2 archivos en uno el form con el select y en el otro el php

Comment: Php se ejecuta en el servidor y JS en el lado del cliente. Se tiene el código en otro archivo para que lo llame de forma asincrónica al PHP, haga la tarea que tenga que hacer y devuelva un resultado sin tener que recargar la página.